# Is it possible to allow checkboxes to be checked by clicking on the label when it has a hidden field on top of it?

Tags: html, cakephp

I have a label with a checkbox and a hidden input in it.
Without the hidden input, I was able to click on the label to check the checkbox, but with the hidden input on top of it, I can't **(Except on Chrome)**.

Is there anyway around this without moving the hidden input (It is crucial that the hidden input is inside the label and on top of the checkbox)?

My JsBin: http://jsbin.com/kovipaxu/7/edit

**Why is it crucial that the hidden field has to be inside the label and on top of the checkbox?**

This is because I'm using CakePHP's form helper.

Input Options

```
$checkbox_options = array(
    'label'       => false,
    'div'         => false,
    'type'        => 'checkbox',
    'class'       => false,
    'hiddenField' => true
);
```

Form:

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <label>
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('field', $checkbox_options); ?>
        My Label Here
    </label>
</div>
```

The above form will output:

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <label>
        <input name="data[FakeModel][field]" value="0" type="hidden">
        <input name="data[FakeModel][field]" value="1" checked="checked" type="checkbox">
        My Label Here
    </label>
</div>
```

If there is a way to move the hidden input below the checkbox using CakePhp's form helper that would be great! But unfortunately I don't think that's possible, I went through the document and couldn't find a way.

Answer (score 0):

Wow about this. Its working on Firefox

```
$checkbox_options = array(
    'label'       => 'My level here',
    'div'         => false,
    'type'        => 'checkbox',
    'class'       => false,
    'hiddenField' => true
);
```